# Unexpected error '=' while subsetting observations in r

Tags: r

I am trying to subset specific observations in a dataset.

I have four columns: `Trial_code`, `Flanker`, `RT` and `correct`

Here is snippet from my dataframe:

```
Trial_code Flanker   RT correct
1    validspatialcue1       1  621       1
2           doublecue       2  730       1
3               nocue       1  796       1
4   invalidspatialcue       1  511       1
5    validspatialcue3       2  736       1
6               nocue       1  593       1
7    validspatialcue2       2  682       1
8           doublecue       2  690       1
9   invalidspatialcue       1  641       1
10   validspatialcue1       1  476       1
11   validspatialcue3       2  573       1
```

I am trying to select and create a dataframe of observations that meet the following criteria

The entry in `Trial_code` should either of these:

`validspatialcue1`, `validspatialcue2`, `validspatialcue3`

and

Values in `Flanker` should be equal to 1

In order to accomplish this I wrote the following code:

```
data1 <- subset(mydata, Trial_code=="validspatialcue1",Trial_code=="validspatialcue2",Trial_code=="validspatialcue3" & Flanker=1)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "data1 <- subset(mydata, Trial_code=="validspatialcue1",Trial_code=="validspatialcue2",Trial_code=="validspatialcue3" & Flanker="
```

Can anyone please help on this because I am not sure what mistake I am doing here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mydata[grepl('^validspatialcue[123]', mydata$Trial_code) & 
       mydata$Flanker == 1, ]
```

Here you provide two arguments.
The first one -grepl(...)- looks in the varaible Trial_code for the following string:

1. That starts the line ("^") with the string "validspatialcue". The start of the line "^" is important to preclude false positives with "*in*validspatialcue".
2. Is followed by either 1, 2 or 3 ("[123]").

The second one looks for cases where mydata equals 1.

The "&" signs instructs the sub-setting to look for the previous conditions to be simultaneously true.

Do not forget the comma "," before closing the braquets!

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Tried implementing the code but now it gives me this error: Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'Trial_code' not found

Answer (score 0):

Your last statement is using `=`, and needs to be `==` instead

```
data1 <- subset(mydata, Trial_code=="validspatialcue1",Trial_code=="validspatialcue2",Trial_code=="validspatialcue3" & Flanker==1)
```